# redirect url already rewritten in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have written htaccess 
my actual url is

```
https://www.example.com/index.php?route=information/partnership_form
```

rewritten as

```
https://www.example.com/for-brands/partner-with-us
```

which works fine as I have written rule as

```
`RewriteRule ^for-brands/partner-with-us$ https://www.example.com/index.php?route=information/partnership_form [NC,L]`
```

but I want redirection if some user visits direclty https://www.example.com/index.php?route=information/partnership_form

to

https://www.example.com/for-brands/partner-with-us

below is my code redirect but I've tried many ways form other links of stackoverflow still I cant find any solution

```
rewriterule ^index\.php?route=information\/partnership_form(.*)$ /for-sports-brands/partner-with-us$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not manipulate querystring like that. You need to use a RewriteCond

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=information/partnership_form [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /for-brands/partner-with-us? [NC,L,R]
```

The **?** at the end of the rewrite target is important as it discards the old querystrings.

Comment: I tried your code but its retuning error The page isn’t redirecting properly and does it make any difference if I write sports in rewriterule like `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /for-sports-brands/partner-with-us? [NC,L,R]`